# Removing headers but keeping page numbers in the same time

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I wrote my diploma in LaTeX using Lyx, but now I have big problem to fit the output to universities' standards.

I need to remove Part/Section... title from header, I found that using:

```
 \pagestyle{empty}
```

does the job, but it also removes page numbers, and I spent more than an hour trying to fit them together, especially that in some pages I need no page numbers, while in others has to start from some number, so I'm using:

```
\setcounter{page}{3}
```

which also conflicts with the first command.

Any help will be highly appreciated, because I need to print it today, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

First of all, to change the behaviour of a single page, you have to use `\thispagestyle` instead of `\pagestyle`, which changes the style from the current page till the end of your document.

Moreover, to have just the page number in the page, you have to use the style `plain` and not the style `empty`.

This means that, to have a single page with only the page number you have to put, in that page:

```
\thispagestyle{plain}
```

The valid options, for both `\thispagestyle` and `\pagestyle` commands are:

- `plain` - Just a plain page number.
- `empty` - Produces empty heads and feet - no page numbers.
- `headings` - Puts running headings on each page. The document style specifies what goes in the headings.
- `myheadings` - You specify what is to go in the heading with the `\markboth` or the `\markright` commands.

Comment: Thx, didn't know about the plain thing, it almost worked, now the problem with Page numbering: at the first page i have `\renewcommand{\partname}{brbrbr}
\thispagestyle{empty}` that suppose to remove everything in headers till i will use \thispagestyle again, right? then after couple pages (3 pages), i use `\thispagestyle{plain}
\setcounter{page}{5}` the result is that first page only has no number, but the second has it, and page numbering is not reseting to 5.

Comment: @TMS The page after the one where `\thispagestyle` has been used, has header and footers as specified in your document class. No need to specify it again unless you want a new page with different behaviour. If, after a couple of pages you need a `plain` page numbered 3, yes, put there `\thispagestyle{plain} \setcounter{page}{3}`

Comment: but you said "from the current page on throughout the remainder of your document" so I understood the same behavior should be inherited till new using of the command. anyway suppose then that I want to not having page numbers for the first "50" pages, it's not reasonable to insert \thispagestyle in each page, is there any other way?

Comment: I meant "till the end of your document". Put `\pagestyle{empty}` at the beginning and at the 50th page `\pagestyle{plain}` or `\pagestyle{.....}` depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Oh I see, worked, thx for fast replay :)