# Remove all headers before chapter 1

Tags: header-footer

I have tried to remove all the headers before chapter 1 and it works on all of the pages but 1.
I have around 10 pages before chapter 1, and page 7 adds the header.

Here is my code so far:

```
\makepsmarks{ase_report}{%
  \renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{%
    \markboth{%
      \ifnum \value{secnumdepth} > 1
      \if@mainmatter % 
      \@chapapp\ \thechapter: \ %
      \fi
      \fi
      ##1}{}}%

  \renewcommand\tocmark{\markboth{}{}}%
  \renewcommand\lofmark{\markboth{}{}}%
  \renewcommand\lotmark{\markboth{}{}}%
  \renewcommand\bibmark{\markboth{\bibname}{\bibname}}%
  \renewcommand\indexmark{\markboth{\indexname}{\indexname}}%
  \renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{\markright{##1}}%
  \renewcommand\subsectionmark[1]{\markright{##1}}%
  \renewcommand\subsubsectionmark[1]{\markright{##1}}%
}
```

I am using frontmatter and mainmatter. Front matter is defined on page 1 and front matter is defined in the beginning of chapter 1.
I hope you can help me.

Note: What I see in the header is "0.0" and nothing more.

Comment: Have you tried simply adding `\pagestyle{empty}` or `\thispagestyle{empty}` at the according places? Really hard to help without code that lets us reprodce the matter.

Comment: Sorry I know it can be hard, but I havent been able to make a small code example that gives the same problem. I will try your suggestions.

Comment: @Johannes_B \thispagestyle{empty} Works like a charm :) Thanks. If you write an answer I will accept it.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [Removing Headers, Keeping Page Numbers in the same time](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120748)